# ServiceManager.getServiceNames() returns null. Why?

Tags: java, jnlp

I had a little app which was able to save and load files. Then I decided to try Java Web Start, so that I needed to rewrite JFileChooser usage to jnlp stuff.

Looking at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/JWSFileChooserDemoProject/src/components/JWSFileChooserDemo.java I've tried to rewrite my code.

Here what I came with

```
FileSaveService fss = null;
FileContents fileContents = null;
ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(
    (new String("Saved by JWSFileChooserDemo").getBytes()));
try {
    String[] services = ServiceManager.getServiceNames();
    fss = (FileSaveService)ServiceManager.
                    lookup("javax.jnlp.FileSaveService");
}
catch (UnavailableServiceException exc) { }

if (fss != null) {
    try {
        fileContents = fss.saveFileDialog(null, null, is, null);
}
```

and so on.

At first there were no `ServiceManager.getServiceNames` call, and my the `ServiceManager.lookup` returned null. So I decided to get the service list, and `getServiceNames` returns null also.

How can I make it to find `FileSaveService`? Where does the method looks for this service, and shouldn't I write some extra stuff somewhere to declare that I need that service?

**UPD:** I've tried to run JWSFileChooserDemo from the oracle's link above, and it doesn't work. Same thing with `ServiceManager.lookup` that returns null.

Comment: Those services are only available when the app. is *launched* using JWS.  They will not be available in an executable Jar that is double clicked.  They will not be available in a `java -jar..` launch from the command line or batch file.  It must be something like [`javaws`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/javaws.html) or launching the JNLP from a link on a local server.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, thanks a lot for the answer!
So... how that could be debugged with eclipse or NetBeans?